# Emacs org-mode export to LaTeX and PDF produces incorrect double quotes

Tags: pdf, emacs, latex

I am currently finishing up the formatting of a book written in Emacs org-mode. I noticed that me using a specific kind of formatting for dialogue produces odd results when it comes to closing double quotes and the characters before them, when exporting from raw text to LaTeX and then to PDF.

Raw text example

```
/"First line of dialogue./
/Second line of dialogue to enforce logical separation and make the speech easier to parse./
/Closing line of dialogue."/
```

To help understand that the dialogue, even if separated into multiple lines, still belongs to the same person, it's standard practice to have the first line start with double quotes and the last line end with double quotes. But at some point in the export/conversion process this fails, as the PDF output has the closing double quotes as OPENING double quotes, I assume because it couldn't find any at the beginning of the line.

Output example

```
“First line of dialogue.
Last line of dialogue.“
```

Expected behaviour

```
“First line of dialogue.
Last line of dialogue.” //Often the character before the double quote is also messed up, like a reverse question mark.
```

Any thoughts on how I can enforce the expected behaviour without manually changing each and every double quote?